# How to use React with a different backend language

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a small website with a backend written in PHP. I would like to use React on the front end, but I am new to front-end development and React, and hence I'm finding this confusing (as each example online that I've found seems to assume or focus on a javascript backend with node modules, etc.).

Using PHP, I believe I want to provide an HTML file as a response containing a reference to a script which uses React.

The typical react-create-app setup appears to use Node as a backend, and imports with statements of the form `import React from 'react'`. However, `import`ing React as above then does not work, so I've used `<script>` tags to 'import' `React` and `ReactDOM`, as so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When attempting to look at other websites using React, I found it confusing to discern what the content they were providing to the user was and how exactly they were ensuring the browser knew React was needed, and where to get it.

Hence, I'm wondering whether this the correct method to get started? Is loading the scripts for React and ReactDOM sufficiently fast? Do I want to go about this method for using React on the front end with a non-javascript backend?

Comment: The backend is pretty much irrelevant. All your doing is sending HTML and JavaScript to the browser. How you do that is up to you. What you may have seen is that people split their code into modules and are then using a module bundler to create a single JS file. These tools are usually written for Node, but they are executed at development time (i.e. on your own machine, or as part of CI), not in production.

Comment: @FelixKling I believe(d) so, which is why I've attempted to use React, but a lot of React support seems to focus on, or even assume, a Javascript backend. If it's indeed all run in the browser, are such `import` statements understood by said browser, when not done in `<script>` tags? As an aside, your comment might be more suitable as an answer.

Comment: This is all taken care of by the module bundler. It takes an entry file, determines dependencies (`import` and `require` statements) and creates a single file. The result file won't have `imports` or `requires` in it (or those will be replaced by something else). Popular bundlers are https://webpack.js.org/ and https://rollupjs.org/guide/en .

Comment: In most projects I've worked on or designed, the backend and the frontend are different projects. A react project is just static files once "built" by dev tools like Webpack, etc. It can be served from anywhere, doesn't need to be served by your Php backend.

Comment: _[How it feels to learn JavaScript in 2016](https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f)_.

Answer (score 0):

You write React with JavaScript and it's purely a method for building the UI on the front end. Within React, you can use various packages to make calls to your back end which can be implemented in anything you want.

If you're serving your page with PHP, simply send the HTML file with a script tag that imports your compiled React code.

You'll basically be doing these things:

1. Write the React code
2. Compile the React code into a single browser-friendly JS file (using [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) or something similar)
3. Include a script tag in your HTML file to import this JS file

Once the HTML is loaded, the JS will do its thing to render your React code. What back end language/technology you use does not make a difference here.

Comment: *"React compiles into JavaScript"* React *is* a JavaScript library. It doesn't need to be compiled. Maybe you are talking about JSX?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, since that's the more commonly used method.

Comment: I'd still be careful not to conflate React with JSX. React is more than just syntax, and giving the impression that React is not JavaScript is very confusing.